# Android - Is it possible to make the start position of the scroll bar inside the padding top of the gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, scrollbar, padding

I have a Gridview with padding top and and an image (with height equal to the padding) in the top. The image overlap Gridview.
It looks something like this:

```
 ----------------
|               .|
|     IMAGE     .|
|               .|
---------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
|--------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
|--------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
|--------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
 ----------------
```

I have a problem with scroll bar position when scrolling gridview.
The scroll bar is start at the top right, bellow the image.

What should I do for the scroll bar to be like this:

```
 ----------------
|                |
|     IMAGE      |
|                |
----------------.|
|  ITEM  ITEM   .|
|---------------.|
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
|--------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
|--------------- |
|  ITEM  ITEM    |
 ----------------
```

Is it possible to make the start position of the scroll bar like that?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put image in scroll bar.

Use Gridview Below imageView.

It will works.

Comment: I construct my layout like this:
      <FrameLayout>
       <GridView>
       <Image>
      </FrameLayout>
And it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to put imageView above Gridview like <FrameLayout> <ImageView> <GridView> </FrameLayout>.  Please share you code here so we got more idea.